# Intent Service blocks UI and causes ANR

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite, android-intentservice, android-anr-dialog

I have to download some data as soon as user logs in to the app. I have put
-the network calls to download this data and 
-the database transactions to write it to sqlite

in an intent service. The data is huge so, saving it to sqlite is taking time. But I'm wondering why the intent service is blocking the UI. I can't navigate through the application. If I click on any button nothing happens. If I click again, app just freezes and eventually causes ANR.

I was using Service earlier. As service runs on main thread, I'm using IntentService. I had concurrent AsyncTasks for downloading each set of data. Now I got rid of those AsyncTasks and handling all the network calls in onHandleIntent method. I'm testing on Android device of version 5.1.1(lollipop).

```
public class MastersSyncService extends IntentService {
private static final String TAG = "MastersSyncService";
private static final int CUSTOMERS_PAGE_LENGTH = 5000;

private Context mContext;
private DataSource dataSource;
private boolean isReset;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private int numOfCustReceived, pageNumber, customersVersion;
private AlertDialog alertDialog;

public MastersSyncService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mContext = MastersSyncService.this;
    dataSource = new DataSource(mContext);

    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        isReset = intent.getBooleanExtra("isReset", false);
    }
    customersVersion = dataSource.customers.getVersion();
    if (customersVersion == 0) {
        dataSource.customers.truncateTable();
    }

    downloadPackingDataMasters();
    downloadCommoditiesMasters(); //makes a network call and writes some simple data to sqlite
    downloadPaymentTypesMasters(); //makes a network call and writes some simple data to sqlite
    downloadReasonsMasters(); //makes a network call and writes some simple data to sqlite
    downloadMeasurementTypesMasters(); //makes a network call and writes some simple data to sqlite
    downloadDocketsMasters(); //makes a network call and writes some simple data to sqlite
    downloadContractsMasters(); //makes a network call and writes some simple data to sqlite
    downloadBookingModesMasters(); //makes a network call and writes some simple data to sqlite
    downloadPincodeMasters(); //makes a network call and writes some simple data to sqlite
    downloadCustomersMasters(); //this method has a recursive network call with pagination. Takes a lot of time

}

public void downloadCustomersMasters() {
    try {

        Globals.lastErrMsg = "";
        String url = VXUtils.getCustomersUrl(customersVersion, pageNumber);
        Utils.logD("Log 1");

        InputStream inputStream = HttpRequest.getInputStreamFromUrlRaw(url, mContext);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            pageNumber++;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            dataSource.beginTransaction();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (Utils.isValidString(line)) {
                    numOfCustReceived++;
                    Utils.logD("line from InputStream: " + line);
                    parseCustomer(line);
                }
            }
            dataSource.endTransaction();
        } else {
            numOfCustReceived = 0;
            Utils.logD(TAG + " InputStream is null");
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception while reading input " + ioe);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (!Utils.isValidString(Globals.lastErrMsg))
            Globals.lastErrMsg = e.toString();
        if (Globals.lastErrMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
            Globals.lastErrMsg = getString(R.string.server_not_reachable);
    }

    if (numOfCustReceived >= CUSTOMERS_PAGE_LENGTH) {
        downloadCustomersMasters();
    } else {
        if (!Utils.isValidString(Globals.lastErrMsg) && pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            Utils.updateTimeStamp(mContext, Constants.CUSTOMERS_DATE_PREF);
        }
    }
}

public void downloadPackingDataMasters() {
    try {

        Globals.lastErrMsg = "";

        int version = dataSource.packingData.getVersion();
        String url = VXUtils.getPackingDataUrl(version); //, imei, versionCode + ""
        Utils.logD("Log 1");
        PackingDataResponse response = (PackingDataResponse) HttpRequest
                .getInputStreamFromUrl(url, PackingDataResponse.class,
                        mContext);

        if (response != null) {
            Utils.logD("Log 4");
            Utils.logD(response.toString());
            if (response.isStatus()) {
                List<PackingDataModel> data = response.getData();
                if (Utils.isValidArrayList((ArrayList<?>) data)) {
                    if (isReset)
                        dataSource.packingData.truncateTable();
                    int val = dataSource.packingData.savePackingData(data, version);
                }
            } else {
                Globals.lastErrMsg = response.getMessage();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (!Utils.isValidString(Globals.lastErrMsg))
            Globals.lastErrMsg = e.toString();
        if (Globals.lastErrMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
            Globals.lastErrMsg = getString(R.string.server_not_reachable);
    }

    if (!Utils.isValidString(Globals.lastErrMsg)) {
        Utils.updateTimeStamp(mContext, Constants.PACKING_DATE_PREF);
    }

}

private final char DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER = '"';
private final char DEFAULT_SEPARATOR_CHARACTER = ',';

private void parseCustomer(String line) {

    char quotechar = DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER;
    char separator = DEFAULT_SEPARATOR_CHARACTER;
    if (line == null) {
        return;
    }

    List<String> tokensOnThisLine = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    boolean inQuotes = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {

        char c = line.charAt(i);
        if (c == quotechar) {
            if (inQuotes && line.length() > (i + 1)
                    && line.charAt(i + 1) == quotechar) {
                sb.append(line.charAt(i + 1));
                i++;
            } else {
                inQuotes = !inQuotes;
                if (i > 2 && line.charAt(i - 1) != separator
                        && line.length() > (i + 1)
                        && line.charAt(i + 1) != separator) {
                    sb.append(c);
                }
            }
        } else if (c == separator && !inQuotes) {

            if (Utils.isValidString(sb.toString())) {
                String str = sb.toString().trim();
                tokensOnThisLine.add(str);
            } else {
                tokensOnThisLine.add(sb.toString());
            }
            sb = new StringBuffer();
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }

    if (Utils.isValidString(sb.toString())) {
        String str = sb.toString().trim();
        tokensOnThisLine.add(str);
    } else {
        tokensOnThisLine.add(sb.toString());
    }
    int customerId = Integer.parseInt(tokensOnThisLine.get(0));
    String custName = tokensOnThisLine.get(2);
    Utils.logD("CUST: " + customerId + " " + custName);
    dataSource.customers.saveCustomerDirect(
            customerId,
            tokensOnThisLine.get(1),
            custName,
            tokensOnThisLine.get(3),
            tokensOnThisLine.get(4),
            tokensOnThisLine.get(5),
            tokensOnThisLine.get(6),
            tokensOnThisLine.get(7),
            Integer.parseInt(tokensOnThisLine.get(8)),
            Integer.parseInt(tokensOnThisLine.get(9)),
            Integer.parseInt(tokensOnThisLine.get(10)),
            Integer.parseInt(tokensOnThisLine.get(11)),
            Integer.parseInt(tokensOnThisLine.get(12)));
}
```

Downloading data is taking several minutes. I can't make the user wait for such long time. Please suggest how to make the UI interactive while the data is being downloaded in the background. Or please suggest ways to save huge number of records to sqlite quickly

Comment: how are you calling this service ?

Comment: I'm calling it from an activity as - startService(new Intent(mContext, MastersSyncService.class));

Comment: I haven't used Intent services in a while ever, but I'm wondering if this has anything to do with your problem: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services